# Golden Age short story about carnivorous aliens that pay humans a license fee to clone them for meat

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, clones

The story is told from the perspective of one of a handful of explorers who encountered the aliens. The explorer is sharing a terrible secret with a colleague: When the explorers encountered the aliens, the aliens politely offered to pay a small royalty fee to clone headless humans for their meat markets. The aliens had already taken DNA samples from each of the explorers and threatened to simply clone bootleg humans if the explorers did not agree to accept the offered royalty fees.

It may have been an Isaac Asimov or Ray Bradbury story, but I am not certain. Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Larry Niven's  "Assimilating Our Culture, That's What They're Doing!" ([ISFDB](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45433)) from his *[The Draco Tavern](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheDracoTavern)* stories as seen on the TV Tropes [To Serve Man](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ToServeMan) page.

> A minor character tells the (protagonist) bartender his tale of being in the first diplomatic mission to the Glig, where they're given standard DNA testing among other things. And then cloned as a meat source. To make matters worse, if humans don't allow this practice, and accept royalties for it, the Glig will just eat bootlegged clone meat.

Found with a search for `science fiction aliens cloned meat -"made out of meat"`

Comment: So now 1978 is the Golden Age?!

Comment: @user14111 *oh the humanity*

Comment: I feel like asking a separate question as to what is meant by "bootlegged clone meat".

Comment: Their [cookbook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_(The_Twilight_Zone)) was a best seller, though

Comment: @Clockwork: More or less exactly what it sounds like. They're going to make copies (well, without the head/brain, because they aren't *cruel*) without paying royalties.

Comment: @user14111: So the OP was mis-remembering the age of the story in their story-ID question.  Are you blaming this answer for not pointing out that 1978 isn't "golden age"?  Or was that just a joke...

Comment: :-D I think it's just a general "that's not old! I grew up with that!" plaint. The story wasn't from the "Golden Age", but it is almost 50 years old...

Comment: “The Golden Age of Science Fiction is twelve"
https://quoteinvestigator.com/2020/10/14/golden-age/

Comment: For me the Golden Age was over when Campbell started publishing articles about Dianetics in *Astounding*. The Silver and Bronze Ages followed, but by 1978 stf was well into its Iron Age.

Comment: Internet archive link: https://archive.org/details/dracotavern00nive